# Need help formatting with shared preference saving

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a simple shop activity which uses `SharedPreferences` to store various data. The problem is that when I click on purchase, I can purchase it multiple times and each time it takes the money from the coins value away. Please help me with this.

This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.shop_layout);
    ImageButton lives = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.lives);
    final Button hardmode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hardmode);
    final Button reversedMode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reversedmode);
    final SharedPreferences shop = getSharedPreferences("Shop", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final int[] livesPrice = {shop.getInt("livesPrice", 10)};
    final int[] hardmodePrice = {shop.getInt("hardmodePrice", 15)};
    final int[] reversedModePrice = {shop.getInt("reverseModePrice", 20)};
    final int[] coins = {shop.getInt("money", 10000)};
    final boolean[] hardmodeBoolean = {shop.getBoolean("hardmode", false)};
    final boolean[] reversedModeBoolean = {shop.getBoolean("reversedMode", false)};
    if(hardmodeBoolean[0]){
        hardmode.setText("Purchased");
    }
    if(reversedModeBoolean[0]){
        reversedMode.setText("Purchased");
    }
    TextView price1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price1);
    final TextView money = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.money);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/cricket.ttf");
    price1.setTypeface(tf);
    price1.setText("=" + livesPrice[0]);
    money.setTypeface(tf);
    money.setText("Coins " + String.valueOf(coins[0]));
    lives.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (coins[0] >= livesPrice[0]) {
                coins[0] = coins[0] - livesPrice[0];
                livesPrice[0] = livesPrice[0] + 10;
                int numberOfLives = shop.getInt("numberOfLives", 1);
                numberOfLives = numberOfLives + 1;
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shop.edit();
                editor.putInt("numberOfLives", numberOfLives);
                editor.putInt("money", coins[0]);
                editor.commit();
                money.setText("Coins " + String.valueOf(coins[0]));
            }
        }
    });
    hardmode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shop.edit();
                    if (coins[0] >= hardmodePrice[0]) {
                        coins[0] = coins[0] - hardmodePrice[0];
                        editor.putBoolean("hardmode", true);
                        editor.putInt("hardmodePrice", 0);
                        editor.putInt("money", coins[0]);
                        editor.apply();
                        money.setText("Coins " + String.valueOf(coins[0]));
                        hardmode.setText("Purchased");
                        hardmodeBoolean[0] = shop.getBoolean("hardmode", true);
                    }
    }
    });
    reversedMode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shop.edit();
                    if (coins[0] >= reversedModePrice[0]) {
                        coins[0] = coins[0] - reversedModePrice[0];
                        editor.putBoolean("reversedMode", true);
                        editor.putInt("reversedModePrice", 0);
                        editor.putInt("money", coins[0]);
                        editor.apply();
                        money.setText("Coins " + String.valueOf(coins[0]));
                        reversedMode.setText("Purchased");
                        reversedModeBoolean[0] = shop.getBoolean("reversedMode", true);
                    }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: So what's the actual issue?

Comment: That when I call the 'editor.apply()' or 'editor.commit()' the PriceValue doesn't change to 0 therefore it can still take that value from the coins

Comment: you dont set it to 0. you set it to coins[0] = coins[0] - livesPrice[0];

Comment: look at your if clause: if (coins[0] >= livesPrice[0]) as long as you have more coins than the costs are you will be able to purchase, like Izu said you are not setting price to 0

Comment: But I am. U see that line 'editor.putInt(HardmodePrice, 0);' thats where I am setting it. The problem is that it sometimes apllies when I quit the activity sometimes doesnt apply at all

Answer (score 0):

try changing

coins[0] = coins[0] - livesPrice[0];

To

coins[0]  -= livesPrice[0] ;

Comment: The problem is not with setting the coins value minud the price. But with the saving of the price to the shared prefs